# Dynamic text mark as title in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite, kibana-7

I have a concat view in vega-lite (kibana) where the first bar plot serves as a selection for the other plots. So if I click in one bar of the bar plot, all other visualizations change accordingly.I also have a dropdown with the same goal.

I would like to have a dynamic title (or text mark) that shows the y label of the bar that I just clicked (or the name in the dropdown). So far I managed to do so, however if there are no selections for the bar, all labels will appear in the same title, which is not great.

I thought that maybe initializing the parameter with a certain value would solve the issue, but if I click in between bars, all values appear and I have the same issue with the title. Furthermore, I would like all bars to be always visible, and just change the opacity of the bar that is clicked.

Below you can find a simplified version of what I mean,

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Two horizonally concatenated charts that show a histogram of precipitation in Seattle and the relationship between min and max temperature.",
  "data": {"url": "data/weather.csv"},
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "location", "type": "nominal"},
        "x": {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "precipitation"},
        "opacity":{"condition":{"param":"click","value":0.2},"value":0.7}
      },
      "params":[{
        "name":"click",
        "select":{"type":"point","encodings":["y"], "on":"click"},
        "bind":{"input":"select","options":["New York", "Seattle"]},
        "value":{"y":"Seattle"}
      },
      {
        "name":"highlight",
        "select":{"type":"point"}
      }
      ],
      "transform":[{"filter":{"param":"click"}}]
    },
    {"layer":[{
      "transform":[{"filter":{"param":"click"}}],
      "mark":"bar",
      "mark":{"type":"text","dy":-50, "dx":30, "fontSize":20},
      "encoding":{"text":{"field":"location","type":"nominal"}}
      
    }]},
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "temp_min", "bin": true},
        "y": {"field": "temp_max", "bin": true},
        "size": {"aggregate": "count"}
      },
      "transform":[{"filter":{"param":"click"}}]
    }
  ]
}
```

[vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABUA7mwAEMNpoBecpIMEBPE1DlQkmOLLdxlTmEnWYECb0biYQ5oYmSGY0EJhsZOpICCZsAGYmOOpwUFp0bromNLImAMpwbpiCcFGyPvQ12YIFcuFaJkxwmIZwHiYIxbU+yAAewYg4cEmYDNmUiipuKKigs4Joi5hIBD1u8OqUUBDEIAC+SjDOsq6YaADaoMjqANYbTP4LHs7KxWRooPZ-iA0jQ4IJlBtBGwbroFph7JMNrI2ANPOtziARkCkGREnx3BsEBV5EoQWCIegsjk8lsdHIzko2DgkLl4UCrj86XpQMykggNlBhFBXkpiLYGHA0AAGSgAJgxYsEEullAA7KcMbzkhB7qBPESBUKRSAIGCcrcViB4YjKWxirclF82D9ZGQdag7iBAQBdRl6ECCmjChkgJjFCmgYo4BgWk1mqAOkBMrnuz0AOTgkQAmhZjeVKtUQN6FeLJZbAeh89hCxqFHrkmWMDQyDBhC3E6bqgmgdbGzg7bJbhrfVakrIIGkLPyPaAQYJ3OogVrpwGjWdTsW6yBmvYprrR0hx5P1NOHsCaPO95bl4ag69h0onq9Lb2Nu4RonlBX+GIpUplFiqAAMx-sCciYKUNCWGWspShiToun8L5wB+QJkuCkLQi0JJWgijbIqitjrhu5yPP4z4gP29qfNczq-ECgGzqCGHoO4CA4AA+qiCxhnomDqBKGIVkx5JvhMXFIFiSi8Wg-GCUoEBQWWoA4niFAEugzgMIO65KPxh4TlO+5zguS7+Mkt7BsOJFAA)

As usual, any help will be more than welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are the changes required:

1. To show both the bars, remove the filter transform from bar chart.
2. Added some changes in `click params` like if someone clicks on empty space, then `nearest` bar will be selected and changed values for `opacity`.

Refer the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABUA7mwAEMNpoBecpIMEBPE1DlQkmOLLdxlTmEnWYECb0biYQ5oYmSGY0EJhsZOpICCZsAGYmOOpwUFp0bromNLImAMpwbpiCcFGyPvQ12YIFcuFaJkxwmIZwHiYIxbU+yAAewYg4cEmYDNmUiipuKKigs4Joi5hIBD1u8OqUUBDEIAC+SjDOsq6YaADaoMjqANYbTP4LHs7KxWRooPZ-iA0jQ4IJlBtBGwbroFph7JMNrI2ANPOtziARkCkGREnx3BsEBV5EoQWCIegsjk8lsdHIzko2DgkLl4UCrj86XpQMykggNlBhFBXkpiLYGHA0AAGSgAdiUEzZqDStggcAxYsEEullAATKcMbzkhB7qBPESBUKRSA1dUoLcViB4YjKWxircFdc2D9ZGQTag7iBAQBdRl6ECCmjChaCirqNAqwRqpSyONqB2YdQSjFMYoU0DFHAMB02sE5D0gJlc-2BgBycEiAE0LNbypVqiBgxrxZL0G3sB3zmbkr2MDQyDBhBOK7by0DnaOcG7ZLcDV2FI9-K9Xe64XQO473CMHaA4CMspao88APpQmH0g2e76-IFYx1k8EbdwIHDX1ELXM9EzbMlEBd9QU-dBv1-UYAOKNBgPVJQIBoSxe1AHE8QoAl0GcBgVzODFMyQWQIDSCx+QDUAQUEdx40dI1KIjK1CK7LsgA) or the below code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Two horizonally concatenated charts that show a histogram of precipitation in Seattle and the relationship between min and max temperature.",
  "data": {"url": "data/weather.csv"},
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "location", "type": "nominal"},
        "x": {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "precipitation"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"param": "click", "value": 0.7, "empty": false},
          "value": 0.2
        }
      },
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "click",
          "select": {
            "type": "point",
            "encodings": ["y"],
            "on": "click",
            "clear": false,
            "nearest": true
          },
          "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["New York", "Seattle"]},
          "value": "Seattle"
        },
        {"name": "highlight", "select": {"type": "point"}}
      ]
    },
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "title": {"text": {"expr": "click_location"}},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "temp_min", "bin": true},
        "y": {"field": "temp_max", "bin": true},
        "size": {"aggregate": "count"}
      },
      "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "click"}}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! In the meanwhile I figured out how to have a dynamic title, instead of a text mark, since the latter doesn't look that good! Just in case someone else is looking for this approach, in my code above we just need to add ```"title":{"text":{"signal":"'This is the chosen city:' + ' ' + click_location"}},``` and the visualization will look much better. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @MTMM yes your title modification is correct, but signals are mostly used in vega. To make use of vega-lite config, you can add `"title": {"text": {"expr": "click_location"}},`. I have updated this in my answer as well.

Comment: I've read that signals are indeed part of vega, but I couldn't find anything with vega-lite, and 'signal' worked, so happy days! In any case, since I am just using vega-lite, I will use your approach! Thanks again!